# 18.04 dual boot problems with ASUS FX503

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics, 18.04

I am having some problems installing 18.04 and showing the screen.
My laptop has a GTX 1050 Graphics,and a I-7 with integrated graphics. I've tried `nomodeset` and `nouveau.modeset=0, i915.modeset=0` and various other kernel params I have seen online.

I have also tried a fresh install of Ubuntu,reformatting the drive, etc. All with no luck. Here is some stuff I have found out along the way.

When I run Ubuntu in the try without installing,  It does in fact load the OS fully; I know this for a fact because I hear a camera noise when I hit print screen. Also, I can connect a additional monitor and combined with the kernel `params(nomodeset, nouveau.modeset=0, i915.modeset=0)` and I can finally see the UI.

I was able to install Ubuntu from this, load up the OS, and I tried to purge all NVidia packages, add in beta drivers, install them. After doing all that I have had still no luck.

How can I debug/fix this?

EDIT. I've done some more research and the problem still happens once i disable the splash screen by removing `quiet splash` from the kernel parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up ditching Ubuntu 18.04 and I am sticking with 17.10 for now.

I ran the installer with `nomodeset` as a kernel parameter and I was able to install Ubuntu. Once it was installed i reran Ubuntu and followed the normal steps for installing beta drivers and I do not have any display problems at all.